# An inequality about compact functions and lsc functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, semicontinuous-functions

I'm reading a proof and it contains the following inequality:

> Suppose $u: E \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is lower semicontinuous and let $u_t$ be a sequence of Lipschitz functions approaching $u$ from below. Let $\{\mu_n\} \rightarrow \mu$ in the weak-* sense. Taking $\phi \in C_c(E)$ where $0 \leq \phi \leq 1$ we get:
>   $$\int_E \phi u_t \, d\mu = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_E \phi u_t \, d\mu_n \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E u_t \, d\mu_n$$

How do you get to the right hand side of that inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the assumption that $u_t:E\to [0,\infty)$, we have $\phi u_t \le 1\cdot u_t$, hence
$$
\int_E \phi u_t \ \mathrm d\mu_n\le \int_E  u_t \ \mathrm d\mu_n.
$$ We then take $\liminf_{n\to\infty}$ on both sides. Note that the LHS is actually convergent since $\phi(x) u_t(x)$ is a bounded continuous function and $\mu_n \to \mu$ weak-$*$ly. Hence, we get
$$
\int_E \phi u_t \ \mathrm d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_E \phi u_t \ \mathrm d\mu_n\le\liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_E  u_t \ \mathrm d\mu_n.
$$

Comment: ah ya, okay, I was worried $u_t$ might be negative, but I guess they can be selected non-negative.